# Convert from 24 to 12 hour format

Tags: c++

I am doing a simple conversion program and am getting a lot of errors I don't really understand. Here is my code that I have done so far. I use visual Studio 2019 and these are all the messages I get for the errors.

```
 error C2062: type 'char' unexpected
 error C2182: 'input': illegal use of type 'void'
 error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'
 message : The initializer contains too many elements
 error C2065: 'AMPM': undeclared identifier
 error C2182: 'convert': illegal use of type 'void'
 error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'
message : The initializer contains too many elements
1> error C2065: 'AMPM': undeclared identifier
: error C2182: 'output': illegal use of type 'void'
1>C:\Users\hp\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source.cpp(17,31): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'
: message : The initializer contains too many elements
: error C2065: 'choice': undeclared identifier
: error C2065: 'choice': undeclared identifier
: error C2065: 'choice': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "Project5.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void input(int& hours24, int& minutes);
void convert(int& hours, char& AMPM);
void output(int hours, int minutes, char AMPM);

int main() {
    cout << "-----------------------------Convert from 24-hour format to 12 hour format--------------------\n";
    int hour, min,
        char choice, AMPM;
    do {
        void input(hour, min);
        void convert(hour, min, AMPM);
        void output(hour, min, AMPM);
        cout << "/n";
        cout << "To complete press y or Y: "; cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
}

void input(int& hours24, int& minutes) {
    cout << "Enter your time in hours and minutes"; cin >> hours24; cin >> minutes;
}

void convert(int& hours, char& type) {
    if (hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
        type = 'P';
    }
    else {
        type = 'A';
    }
}

void output(int hours, int minutes, char type) {
    cout << "In 12 hour notation: " << hours << ":" << minutes << " " << type << "";
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the error in the int main and added a semi-colon.

Comment: when you get errors you should include them in the question. Chances are high that if others compile the same code they can get different errors (different compiler, different c++ standard, different compiler flags...)

Comment: Alright I fixed some of the errors, and the only error I get now is my convert function cannot take 3 arguments

Comment: as a general advice: dont write a wall of code and then be surprised that it is full of errors. The problem really is not "full of errors" (we all make typos all the time)  but the "surprise". Write one line maybe two, see if it still compiles, then write more

Comment: Alright I will take your advice into consideration

Comment: @idclev463035818 or better yet use a modern IDE that does real-time intellisense or equivalent

Comment: @bolov I am forced to use an IDE whose equivalent is not quite reliable, hence I tend to not trust anybody but my compiler ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 you can still use it if you also apply some common sense. It's a help tool. But other than that yes, I 101% agree, the compiler has always the last say.

Comment: Consider adding 00:30 as an input to your unit tests.  It should map to 12:30 AM.

Answer (score 0):

```
void input(hour, min);
void convert(hour, min, AMPM);
void output(hour, min, AMPM);
```

That's not how you call a function, try this

```
input(hour, min);
convert(hour, min, AMPM);
output(hour, min, AMPM);
```

Then

```
cout << "/n";
```

The newline character is `\n`, like this

```
cout << "\n";
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't notice that, well now it says the function convert does not take 3 arguments

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar That's quite correct, it only takes two.

Comment: I want the program to carry on while the choice is y or Y and exit when it is anything else (As in 'N' or 'n')

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar OK, but shouldn't the message say something like "To carry on press y or Y" then?

Comment: Yes it's up there but it is worded differently, "To complete press y or Y" It works either way, thank your for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

void input(int& hours24, int& minutes);
void convert(int& hours, char& AMPM);
void output(int hours, int minutes, char AMPM);

int main() {
    cout << "-----------------------------Convert from 24-hour format to 12 hour format--------------------\n";
    int hour, min; // different types. should add simicolon here.
    char choice, AMPM;

    do {
        // just write the name of the functions without their return type.


        input(hour, min);
        // don't pass "min" here.
        convert(hour, AMPM);
        output(hour, min, AMPM);
        cout << "/n";
        cout << "To complete press y or Y: "; cin >> choice;


    } while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
}


void input(int& hours24, int& minutes) {
    cout << "Enter your time in hours and minutes"; cin >> hours24; cin >> minutes;

}

void convert(int& hours, char& type) {
    if (hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
        type = 'P';
    }
    else {
        type = 'A';
    }
}

void output(int hours, int minutes, char type) {

    cout << "In 12 hour notation: " << hours << ":" << minutes << " " << type << "";

}
```

Here is the code fixed with a comment above each fix.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by don't pass "min"  here?

Comment: The function takes only 2 parameters. If you look at the declaration of the ``convert``, It takes only 2 parameters. Yet you're passing 3 arguments. Note that the function ``convert`` doesn't use the variable ``min`` anyways.

Comment: Oh alright, must have been typo, well I better check every 2-3 lines on the compiler, sorry about that.